# Benefits to adding a 32mm Pössl to my Celestron AstroMaster 130EQ's eyepieces?

Tags: telescope, amateur-observing, optics

I am getting a Celestron AstroMaster 130EQ soon. I have heard that its eyepieces aren't the best, so I am considering a 32mm [Pössl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eyepiece#Pl%C3%B6ssl_or_%22Symmetrical%22).

For such a choice, what would be the arguments for and against? How would my viewing experience improve, and for what objects would this be most and least obvious?

Comment: Which eyepieces does it come with? Do you know their focal lengths and fields of view?

Comment: From Celestron's product page: "Accessories include a 20mm and 10mm eyepiece" Welcome to Astronomy.SE.

Comment: @B--rian advice on telescope accessories or "how to choose" questions may seem subjective but they have always been generally welcomed and answered here in Astronomy SE even though some amount of opinion is involved. However, "which should I buy" is what is called in Stack Exchange a "Shopping Question" and is generally off-topic everywhere because it can lead to commercial promotion and advertisements in the form of posts. [Why are “shopping list” questions bad?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158809/303080) (7 answers)

Comment: @JacobKurzawa Welcome to Astronomy SE! I've adjusted the wording of your question to make sure it stays on-topic here in Astronomy SE. We can't ask "Should I buy X?" but we can certainly ask for advice about it and what points to consider. Voting to **keep this question open!**

Comment: @uhoh I just retracted my close-vote. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

The question is a bit old, so I'm sure the person who asked already has their telescope by now.

For starters, the AstroMaster 130EQ is not recommended. [Celestron has acknowledge that it uses a spherical mirror](https://www.celestron.com/blogs/knowledgebase/does-my-astromaster-130-have-a-spherical-or-parabolic-mirror-what-is-the-difference), and as such it produces insufficiently accurate focus for activities such as planetary observing.

However, to answer the original question, a 32mm Plossl is an excellent choice of eyepiece to have in a kit of eyepieces for this telescope. A 32mm Plossl provides the widest possible true field of view you can get in a 1.25" barrel. it also provides a bright exit pupil of 32/5 = 6.4mm. This would then let it work well with nebula filters (UHC, O-III, H-Beta) for teasing out faint details in dim nebulae.

If your telescope has a 1.25" focuser, and the focal ratio is F/5 or greater, a 32mm Plossl is a recommended staple eyepiece to have in your kit.